# Attach File Through mailto URI

Tags: javascript, email, attachment, mailto

Is it possible to attach a file using "mailto:" redirect in javascript?

Something like this:

```
document.location = "mailto:"+recipient+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+msg+"?attach="+"file1.zip";
```

Comment: Only if file1.zip is already on every recipients computer. I think.

Comment: I intend to send a generated log file, when the user clicks on the Email icon in HTML page

Is it possible ?

Comment: You should just send this log file as text in body.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, you can not add an attachment to a message with the `mailto:` URL scheme.

`mailto:` only supports header values or `text/plain` content. See [RFC 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) for details.

Comment: +1 It clearly states on there "Only the Subject, Keywords, and Body headers are believed to be both safe and useful."

Comment: Thanks, if I have to send a file as an attachment(through program)  how would you suggest do it ??

Comment: @Kiran: see my answer for this.

Comment: This was possible on some older systems, per https://x.com/jensvoid/status/1295724959709437956?s=20.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom email form, letting the user input a valid email-address if necessary and send this to the server. The server then can use a mail library to send an email including an attachment.

If you use PHP, you can easily do this using [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/).