# Is it possible attach a file to an Email in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Attach File Through mailto URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372036/attach-file-through-mailto-uri)

I have an HTML link like

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Hello">Send Mail</a>
```

I would like attach a file in the Mail Client when a User click the this link.

Is it possible in JavaScript or using jQuery, html5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try MS ActiveX:

```
var OA = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');
var OAItem = OA.CreateItem(0);

var OAItemAtms = OAItem.Attachments;
OAItemAtms.add('http://foo.com/some_image.png');
```

You can read more on this here - [compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajnishkaushik/archive/2007/05/06/compose-and-send-e-mail-from-javascript-by-using-outlook-automation-2007.aspx)

Comment: Yep, but it's still a solution :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_usage and dropping. You won't target one quarter of the market with that. :-(

Comment: Well... 23.65% usage of IE. That's m.b. quite enough and @GibboK didn't say anything about certain browser he wants to use his code in:)

Comment: Bear in mind that [**IE no longer supports this**](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/05/06/a-break-from-the-past-part-2-saying-goodbye-to-activex-vbscript-attachevent/#5ftMjdBRywuiEqYe.97). ActiveX is well and truely dead

Answer (score 1):

No.

And of course JQuery won't help since that is also Javascript.

You really need something serverside to manage this for you.