# How can I connect to Default mail Client and send an attachment?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, scripting

I have the following options

1. Using `System.Net.Mail` namespace and send mail through `SMTPClient`
2. Connecting to Outlook specifically and adding attachment
3. Using 'MailTo' function in javascript, which does not add 'Attachment'

But none of them are apt for my requirement, where I need to add an attachment to the Default mail client on the user's system.

Is there any way to do that?

MailTo Option- Can I add attachment to this?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSend" Text="Send" runat="server" onClientclick="OpenMail()" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function OpenMail()
{    
location.href='mailto:dummy@gmail.com?subject=Message Title&body=Message Content';   
}
</script>
```

Comment: What code sample do you currently have that you can show us..? also this is very simple if you care to venture out to the land of the World Wide Web, there are 1000's of examples on how to do this.. especially with C#

Comment: I need to add an attachment to the default mail client, like outlook or any other mailing service. I am able to add subject, body but not attachment.

Comment: Is the file on the client or the server?  Since `mailto:` is purely client-side how do you intend to send the file to the client if it's on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attach File Through mailto URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372036/attach-file-through-mailto-uri)

Comment: @user1208862 not posible to use attachment in `mailto:`

Comment: Ok,Is there any other way to attach a file to the Default mail Client in the user system?

Comment: My requirement is like, As soon a user clicks a button, the default mail client should be opened with the information like Email address, Subject, Body, Attachment. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on the server then you can't use the *client's* email program to automatically send it as an an attachment.  Some alternatives:

1. Have the client fill out an "email form" (from, to, message, etc.) and send from the server using `SMTPClient`
2. Send using `mailto:` tags with a *link* to the file within the email `body`

If you try to have the user download the file *then* send using `mailto:` there are too many opportunities for the link to be broken.  You don't know where the file will be downloaded to, if the user changes the name, etc.

Why is using the client's email program a hard requirement?

Comment: I have already checked out the 1st Option. It doesnt fit the requirement. The requirement is to use a default mail client, not sending the mail from the Web Page.

Comment: The 2nd Option, i.e sending the link of the file within the Email body doesnt show as attachment in the Generated Mail..

Comment: @user1208862 You can't send a file from the server using the client's email program without the user downloading the file first.  And you can't guarantee that the file is saved to a specific location with a specific name.  The user will have the ability to change both of those from the browser.

Comment: @user1208862 Regarding your second comment - Because it's not an attachment, it would be a hyperlink that the recipient could use to get the file off of the server site.