# how to take a form to pdf file in email

Tags: html, forms, pdf

Is it possible to code a html form (with jquery validation and all the other tips and tools) and when "send" button is pressed, it send a PDF of this form to an email... for reference and print !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "..it send...", the "it" will more than likely be your server sending the PDF, not the jQuery code in your .js file.  Read up here to learn more...

[Attach File Through mailto URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372036/attach-file-through-mailto-uri)

Comment: i have used : class.phpmailer.php. make the whole thing much easyer